# Protractor- Timeout while Identifying a nested dropdown element based on a condition

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to identify and select a heavly nested dropdown in my application having following structure(Not exact):

```
<tr>..</tr> 
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>
        <grid-field field-name="abc">
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <select>
                            <option value="xyz">Some option</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </span>         
            </span>
        </grid-field>
    </td>
    <td>
        <grid-field field-name="environment">
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <select>
                            <option value="xyz">Some option</option>    /// Required Dropdown
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </span>         
            </span>
        </grid-field>
    </td>
    <td>
        <grid-field field-name="adasd">
            <span>
                <span>
                    <span>
                        <select>
                            <option value="xyz">Some option</option>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                </span>         
            </span>
        </grid-field>   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
```

I have written the following helper function to select the dropdown and I am getting a timeout error.

```
this.selectValueFromDropDown = function(columnName,dropDownData){
    this.getDropDown(columnName).$("[value='".concat(dropDownData).concat("']")).click();
};

this.getDropDown = function(columnName){
    return element.all(by.tagName('tr')).filter(function(row){
        return row.all(by.tagName('grid-field')).each(function(gridField){
            gridField.getAttribute('field-name').then(function(attribute){
                return attribute === columnName;
            });
        });
    }).first().element(by.tagName('select'));
};


// Spec
gridObject.selectValueFromDropDown('environment','xyz');
```

**Error Message**

```
> Message:
>     Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.   Stack:
>     Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
>         at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\Users\taaupsa1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1812:23)
```

Could any one tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the error traceback? On which line the error is thrown? Do you see the option being selected? Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe I do not see the option being selected and I have updated the error message now and also the code. Thanks

Comment: Could you also post how you are using the `selectValueFromDropDown` in your spec? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, here is a theory. You are missing the `return` from the `each()` call making it executing "forever" and exceeding the default jasmine spec timeout:

```
this.getDropDown = function(columnName){
    return element.all(by.tagName('tr')).filter(function(row){
        return row.all(by.tagName('plm-grid-field')).each(function(gridField){
            // v HERE
            return gridField.getAttribute('field-name').then(function(attribute){
                return attribute === columnName;
            });
        });
    }).first().element(by.tagName('select'));
};
```

And, I also think you meant to use `filter()` instead of `each()`..

Comment: I added the return statement and also tried using the filter() but I still face the same problem. :(

Comment: @SaiUpadhyayula okay, what is you would increase the [default timeout interval](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts-from-jasmine)?

Comment: Thanks,Increasing the time out to 100000 is producing different error message now, 

the output of the first filter is undefined, I think I am doing something wrong inside the filter()

Comment: Error message now - "Failed: No element found using locator: By.tagName("select")"

Comment: @SaiUpadhyayula could you post the code you have now? Thanks. Also, should not you be looking for `td` elements and not `tr`? (though it is probably not relevant)